# Angular 6 vendor.js file size too big

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm building with my Angular 6 project with CLI 1.6 with `ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer=true`

My vendor.js is 7MB (non-compressed), which seems too large. Angular itself is 1.92MB, with Core being 720KB, Forms being 218KB, Router being 211KB. Lodash and Moment each account for 500KB, which again seems to big, since their browser CDN versions are 75KB and 15KB.

What am I doing wrong?

Screenshot of Webpack Analyzer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXNP1.jpg

Comment: Did you have your e2e/spec files excluded from build? Have you got something inside "include" in your tsconfig? try with this flags: --prod --aot --extract-css --build-optimizer --optimization